# init.vim cannot be found

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

I hope this question is a duplicate one because I have already tried to find `init.vim` inside the nvim folder but I am unable to locate the file.
Also, would I have to create it explicitly or would it be automatically created on installation?
Kindly help me out.
Both of these folders are empty.

```
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\nvim
```

```
C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\nvim-data
```

I am using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neovim won't create the `~/AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim` file during installation. You will have to create it yourself.

The easiest way to confirm it's being loaded is to create the file with:

```
:echoerr "init.vim is loaded"
```

Which should show an error message on startup.

Comment: shows init.vim is loaded while the folders are empty.